# Private PaaS v/s Public PaaS v/s Self-managed Private PaaS

Tags: openshift, paas, google-anthos

I have been trying understand the difference between Private PaaS v/s Public PaaS v/s Self-managed Private PaaS.

My understanding till now is that (and please correct me if I am wrong) a private PaaS is deployed on-premises while a public PaaS is deployed on the premises of vendor.

Below are my questions:

- A public PaaS like Google Anthos can be deployed on-premise as well, and if that happen then does it becomes private PaaS?
- What is self-managed private PaaS, and what are the
  examples and how it is different from "private PaaS"?
- Is Red Hat's OpenShift an example of self-managed private
  PaaS?

Answer (score 0):

> A public PaaS like Google Anthos can be deployed on-premise as well, and if that happen then does it becomes private PaaS?

You can use GKE On-premisses to integrate your bare-metal service as GKE nodes, but the master nodes will remain in the Cloud. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/on-prem/overview) you can read more about GKE On-Premises.

> What is self-managed private PaaS, and what are the examples and how it is different from "private PaaS"?

A private PaaS means you have all installation done and managed by you and not by the cloud provider. Some examples are RedHat Openshift and Rancher cluster. Bot can can be installed in the cloud but managed by you.

> Is Red Hat's OpenShift an example of self-managed private PaaS?

Yes, it is. You can use some cloud provider to install, but still being a private PaaS.